# What to do with Azure error "Premium V2 is not supported for this scale unit. Please consider redeploying or cloning your app."

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I need to change an app service pricing tier from S1 to P2V2, in order to match our production settings for load testing.

When I go to do this P2V2 is not possible I see:

"Premium V2 is not supported for this scale unit. Please consider redeploying or cloning your app"

What does this mean and what do I do to fix? Should I create a new plan and redeploy all the resources in the plan, or should I clone each app and then delete the old one?

[image]

Comment: See if these links helps: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dacceaeb-953b-429d-9b0f-9852af2f8391/web-apps-upgrade-path-from-basic-b1-to-premium-p1v2, https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/35089333-allow-scale-up-to-premium-v2-without-redeploy-or-c and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#if-you-get-an-error.

Comment: Very very helpful, thank you.